# Convert a string to object key lookup in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a use case where I need to use a string to match object values

For example

```
'one': {
    'two': {
            'three': 'val'
        }
    }
}
```

`split` and `reduce` seems to be the way to go about this, but I have not gotten it to work using the code below

```
const string = 'one.two.three';
const test = string
             .split('.')
             .reduce((obj, key) => {
                 return obj[key]
             });
console.log(test); 
//expected one['two']['three']
```

[ Edit to add more context ] 
I have an HTML Template (angular 7) that calls the sort function

```
(click)="sortColumn('spn.subscriptionId')"
```

I have the following object to keep track of sort order for each column

```
public sortableColumns = [
    { colName: 'name', colSortDir: 'none'},
    { colName: 'spn.subId', colSortDir: 'none'},
    { colName: 'regionName', colSortDir: 'none'},
    { colName: 'customerName', colSortDir: 'none'}
];
```

and the `sortColumn` function. `this.subscriptions` comes from a rest api. the sort function works if there is a rest api object only has one level - 'name' but does not work for the nested object - `spn.subscriptionId`

```
public sortColumn(column : string) {
    // resets other columns 
    this.sortableColumns.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.colName !== column) {
            el.colSortDir = 'none';
        }
    });

    // matches the column name passed with sortableColumns to set order in UI
    const col = this.sortableColumns.filter((el) => {
        return el.colName === column;
    });

    // sorting of the array object. this.subscriptions comes fr
    if (col[0].colSortDir === 'asc') {
        col[0].colSortDir = 'dsc';
        this.subscriptions.sort((val1, val2) => {
            if (val1[column] < val2[column]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (val1[column] > val2[column]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    } else if (col[0].colSortDir === 'none' || col[0].colSortDir === 'dsc') {
        col[0].colSortDir = 'asc';
        this.subscriptions.sort((val1, val2) => {
            if (val1[column] > val2[column]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (val1[column] < val2[column]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: I don't need to access the value of the object, but rather construct the lookup key one['two']['three'] as this then gets used in a sorting function for a table

Comment: There is no "lookup key" though. `one['two']['three']` is essentially meaningless, unless you plan on using `eval` to get the data, in which case you might as well use your original `'one.two.three'`. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to show more of how the output is used in this sorting function, we can help you get what you need.

Comment: thanks, I have edited my questions to add more context.

Comment: I'd suggest making the code a [mcve] so that someone can drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate the issue.  It looks like you're not passing the actual object you want to start with into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic "lookup key" that you can plug in to the bracket notation `obj[key]` and have it traverse multiple nested objects.

Given your expected use case, it makes the most sense to have a lookup function that takes a compound key and uses your `.split().reduce()` method to fetch the desired value in the nested objects.

So, something like this:

```
function lookup(obj : object, key : string) : any {
    return key.split('.').reduce((o, k) => o && o[k], obj);
}
```

Used like this:

```
    this.subscriptions.sort((val1, val2) => {
        return lookup(val1,column) - lookup(val2,column);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem was not passing the actual object in as [the `initialValue` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters).

We can write a `nestedProp()` function which takes an object and a path string and walks through it:

```
function nestedProp(obj: object, path: string): unknown {
    return path.split(".").reduce((o, k) => o ? (o as any)[k] : undefined, obj);
}
```

All I've really done is add `obj` as `initialValue`.  I also guard against `o[k]` being `null` or `undefined` so that the code doesn't throw runtime errors if you pass a bad string.

Also note that the type definitions I've given are really very loose; `obj` is any `object`, `path` is any `string`, and it returns [`unknown`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).  That's because TypeScript can't do string manipulation at the type level, so it has no idea that `"one.two.three".split(".")` will result in `["one", "two", "three"]` and therefore no idea that `nestedProp()` should produce a `string` instead of an `undefined` which is what happens when you pass in, say, `"oops.not.a.property"`.  It's possible to tighten the definitions up a little, but it doesn't seem worth it.  To be safe you should test that the output is what you want.

---

So, let's test it.  Say your object is this:

```
const myObj = {
    'one': {
        'two': {
            'three': 'val'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call `nestedProp()` like this:

```
const res1 = nestedProp(myObj, "one.two.three");
console.log(res1); // "val"
console.log((typeof res1 === "string" ? res1 : "oops").toUpperCase()); // VAL

const res2 = nestedProp(myObj, "three.two.one");
console.log(res2); // undefined
console.log((typeof res2 === "string" ? res2 : "oops").toUpperCase()); // OOPS
```

Looks good to me.  Note that I'm testing if the output is a `string` before assuming it is one, and using `"oops"` in the case that it isn't.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeBYAKBmJgHJwBTUgLlxkJMbKgHcQbcGnvSoALAE4UqtUgDcAhgBtSXbgF85MRQRWEAZgFcwwKAEtwMMBWgUAJgAUBIAA4AKEOlqO0FXQBoYNif1rQBemAA5gCUtNoA1mAgLGCcRCRCUJoCcd78AHQQNlJ6UHYARBkFIRlCZprAFHYOnhEhWAB8MCAwAPwwDjASEN1gCCEA2hEAujDhYGYU6oHmni4hANyEagSgkLBCEACMWEYmUOZWtnaIqGieBZQZrCA3gsIly2vgECBSFBlSIEF2W9tLGAAeiBMAKkikBUI6zeHy+PxqUAQNgoIHUMH+WEw2AK-kCQQK7QxJl2tCutggJRuIAAqjYUQIAMI9aohQEgmAANQAggAZQjQ16bEwAJj2xlMlms9jO6Eu-CEn1uGUoT0FkHen2+vy2IvZoO0UxmxjM6thWoRdiRKLRxIgYuxOLxwUJHV14zBIApVKgtPpFCZLLsbMWwNBSCQFgAygKCEA)

Comment: ...the `nestedProp` function being what the proposed duplicate answered, using JavaScript, so minus the type decorations...

Answer (score -1):

```
let string = "one.two.three.four.five.six";

let stringArr = string.split('.');
let obj = {
  [stringArr[stringArr.length - 1]]: "value",
}
for (let i = stringArr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
  this[stringArr[i]] = obj
  obj = Object.assign({}, this)
  delete this[stringArr[i]]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

This works for any number of nesting.

```
{"one":{"two":{"three":{"four":{"five":{"six":"value"}}}}}}
```

I hope this is what you want